# Import Rhinoceros file in OpenModelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica, .obj, rhinoceros

I want to import to OpenModelica a Rhinoceros file.

As far as I know, I can’t import it as .3dm, but I’m trying to import it in .obj with ModelicaServices libraries. I can’t figure it out, any sugestions?

I’ve tried:

```
model Modelname
  ModelicaServicies.Utilities.ReadFile(“pathOfTheFile.obj);
equation 
end Modelname;
```